# MLE of $\theta$ when $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a random sample from $U(2\theta,5\theta)$

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n$ be a random sample from uniform $(2\theta, 5\theta), \,\theta>0$.

Let $X_{(n)} = \max \{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ and $X_{(1)} = \min \{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$. Find the Maximum Likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

---

I think the answer is

MLE of $\theta$ is $\frac {X_{(n)}}{5}$.  Is it correct?

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots, X_{n}$ are iid and $X\sim U(a,b)$ where $x\in[a,b]$.

$$f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}
1, \,\,\,a\leq x\leq b \\
0, \,\text{   otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The likelihood function is:

$$L(a,b; x)=\bigg(\frac{1}{b-a}\bigg)^{n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{a\leq x_{i}\leq b\}}$$

Now we can't use calculus to solve for a maximum. However, we know that:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{a\leq x_{i}\leq b\}}=\begin{cases}
1, \,\,\,a\leq x_{i}\leq b, \forall i \\
0, \,\text{   otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Therefore, to maximize, we need $b\geq x_{(n)}$ and $a\leq x_{(1)}$ (otherwise the product goes to zero).

Similarly, we know $\Big(\frac{1}{b-a}\Big)^{n}$ is a decreasing function of $b$ and increasing function of $a$. Thus, we need the smallest value of $b$ that is at least as large as $x_{(n)}$ and the largest value of $a$ that is smaller than or equal to $x_{(1)}$.

Hence we arrive at:

$$\hat{b}^{\text{MLE}}=x_{(n)}$$

$$\hat{a}^{\text{MLE}}=x_{(1)}$$

With regards to your question, given your solution, I can only guess you meant for your samples to come from $X\sim U(a,5\theta)$, which in the case of the solution provided would be $b=5\theta$ and $\hat{\theta}^{\text{MLE}}=x_{(n)}/5$.

---

For the case of dependent bounds i.e. $X\sim U(c\theta,d\theta)$, the derivation is as follows:

Given, $0\leq c < d$:

$$L=\bigg(\frac{1}{\theta(d-c)}\bigg)^{n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{c\theta\leq x_{i} \leq d\theta\}}$$

and

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{c\theta\leq x_{i} \leq d\theta\}}=\begin{cases}
1, \,\,\,c\theta\leq x_{i}\leq d\theta, \forall i \\
0, \,\text{   otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Or equivalently,

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{c\theta\leq x_{i} \leq d\theta\}}=\begin{cases}
1, \,\,\,x_{i}/d\leq \theta\leq x_{i}/c, \forall i \\
0, \,\text{   otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

i.e. $c\theta\leq x_{(1)}$ and $d\theta\geq x_{(n)}$ giving $x_{(n)}/d\leq \theta \leq x_{(1)}/c$.

This gives, $\theta\in [x_{(n)}/d,\,x_{(1)}/c]$.

Thus, for any value of $\theta$ in that range, the product is maximized at 1. Given that we know $\Big(\frac{1}{\theta(d-c)}\Big)^{n}$ is a decreasing function of $\theta$, we need to choose the smallest value of $\theta$ in that interval.

Therefore, we arrive at $\hat{\theta}^{\text{MLE}}=x_{(n)}/d$. Interestingly, the MLE is independent of $c$.

Comment: X(1)/2 will also be maximum likelihood?I have little idea..Plz help me...Does MLE will be any number in the interval (X(1)/2 , X(n)/5))

Comment: @Halima.Khatun Refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997209/mle-of-uniform-distribution-with-dependent-bounds

Comment: @Halima.Khatun Is this an acceptable answer?

Comment: Good derivation, but you're missing some details. Suppose $c=2$, $d=5$ as in the OP,  and assume the sample is $\{10,10,10,2\}$. Then $x(n)/5=10/5=2$ and $x(1)/2=2/2=1$. Then  $x(n)/d>x(1)/c$ which seems contradicts one of the steps of your derivation. You need to add the condition that, since the sample is drawn from $[c\theta,d\theta] $, then samples such that  $x(n)/d>x(1)/c$ are possible, but have probability 0.

Comment: @DeltaIV But the dataset you generated from $X\sim U(2\theta,5\theta)$ is impossible for any $\theta$ i.e. $x_{i}=\{2,10,10,10\}$ cannot come from this $X$.

Comment: @StatsPlease I disagree: it's not impossible, it has zero probability. $X \sim U(0,1)$ can attain values outside of $[0,1]$, but with probability 0. As a matter of fact, when you write the likelihood, you dont' say that $L$ is impossible to calculate when $x_i \not\in [c\theta, d\theta]$ for some $i$, but just that it's zero.

Comment: @DeltaIV You're probably right. I'm coming from the angle that, given the data $x_{i}=\{2,10,10,10\}$, it would be a pointless exercise to find the MLE of $\theta$ because you immediately see that this cannot be the distribution for the data.